# h2o package in R and python

Tags: python, r, package, h2o

Will all functions in R and python work on the h2o package? Are they any restrictions like some functions work and other functions do not work?

Comment: The short answer here is no.  The h2o package is only an API for executing H2O commands.  That being said the package attempts to mimic some of the R function naming.  Using R as an example, you can get a quick feel for the functions in the h2o package by browsing the reference manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking: is the background that you're trying to decide whether to use R or Python?

Comment: No.. we are currently using both R and Python. Purpose of moving to H2o for faster computation. So, just want to conform whether normal functions what we use in R and python will work? when we use H20.

Comment: Normal functions will not work without some re-coding.

Answer (score 0):

H2O is a platform for Machine Learning written from scratch in Java, and a collection of specific algorithms re-implemented from scratch in Java to be parallel and distributed.

The H2O package for R and Python exposes this specific set of algorithms available in the H2O platform.  The H2O R/Python package use a REST API underneath the hood to talk to an H2O cluster (including the case of a cluster of size 1 running on your local machine).  So it's a client/server architecture.

Here is a link describing the H2O software architecture:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/architecture.html

R and Python of course also have thousands of other packages (many of which are actually implemented in Fortran and C).  What H2O does not do is take an arbitrary R package written in Fortran and magically parallelize and distribute it on the Java-based H2O platform.

Think of the H2O package as another package that implements several algorithms (GBM, for example) in a scalable way really well; as something that can be used side-by-side to complement your existing R/Python packages in RStudio/Jupyter, rather than trying to replace all of them.